# Read special character in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I'm working with font awesome icons and use them as:

```
#header > nav > a[href="#menu"]::before {
    content: '\f0c9';
}
```

And I want to write some code which will change this icon to another after click:

```
var style = $('<style />').appendTo('head');
$("#three_rows").click(function() {
    style.text("#header>nav>a[href='#menu']:before{content:'\f00d'}");
});
```

This code works good if I use some simple text in `content` property, but when I tried to put another fa-icon shortcode it did nothing.

As I understand the problem is in `"\"` character.

How can I use it `"\"` in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` by using another `\`:

```
var style = $('<style />').appendTo('head');
$("#three_rows").click(function() {
    style.text("#header>nav>a[href='#menu']:before{content:'\\f00d'}");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not the easy way?

Add a class with javascript when you click on the element.
That's all you need to do with javascript.

```
$("#three_rows").click(function() {
    $("#header>nav>a[href='#menu']").addClass('blubb');
});
```

and in your CSS add.

```
#header > nav > a[href="#menu"].blubb::before {
    content: '\f00d';
}
```

Cause CSS changes the style, so keep it there.

Of course you can change the class names to what ever makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot affect pseduo elements directly by using jQuery. You also should not inject styling rules in to the page using plain text in a `<style>` element. It's a really, really hacky solution, and far better are available.

For instance, you can simply add a `class` to the required parent element, then hook your CSS rules to change the icon based on that class, something like this:

```js
$("#three_rows").click(function() {
  $('#header > nav > a[href="#menu"]').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#header > nav > a[href="#menu"]::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0c9";
}

#header > nav > a[href="#menu"].active::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f00d";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div id="header">
  <nav>
    <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<p>
  <button id="three_rows">Click me</button> 
</p>
```